# Spring boot - Not an managed type class - some class

Tags: spring-boot

public class Flight {

```
private LocalDateTime departureTime;
private AirPort departurePlace;
private AirPort arrivalPlace;
private Crew crew;
private Plane plane;
```

}

Comment: Please include a question, the errors/issues, and relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

if it is an persistence entity, please add @Entity and @Table(name="table name") on top of the class